# Prove that a function similar to Dirichlet is continuous under some condition.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

The question is given below:

[image]

Could anyone give me a hint for the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

Use sequential criterion to show $f$ is continuous exactly at where $\sin\vert x \vert\equiv0 $ .

**Added** : Let $x \neq k \pi, k \in \Bbb{Z}$

If $\{x_n\} \in \Bbb{Q}$  such that $x_n \rightarrow x$, then by continuity of sine function, $$\lim f(x_n)=\lim \sin \vert x_n \vert=\sin (\lim \vert x_n \vert )=\sin \vert x \vert \neq 0$$ 
Whereas if  $\{x_n\} \in \Bbb{Q}^c$  such that $x_n \rightarrow x$, then $$\lim f(x_n)=0$$
so $f$ is discontinuous at    $x \neq k \pi, k \in \Bbb{Z}$

Comment: this is the whole proof?

Comment: could u provide more details please?

Comment: @hopefully: For continuity at $x=k \pi$ to prove for every sequence  $x_n$ converges to $x$ , the image sequence $f(x_n)$ must converge to $f(x)$, so here   this $x$ is irrational for $k \neq 0$ .so $f(x)=0$.  So we prove $x_n \rightarrow x \Longrightarrow f(x_n) \rightarrow 0$, so first take $x_n$  is rational and see what will happen and then take $x_n$  to be  irrational and see what will happen!